# Autofill data gets overwritten by onchange event of javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I am facing a very annoying issue. I have a form with all empty field initially. Now user has a option to use default set of values by choosing a radio button 'yes' option.

If the user chooses to use default set of values then I fill all the form fields with default set of values using script. Everything goes fine till now.

The problem is my select drop-down not getting set with the default value. After debugging I found out that it is getting set but then On Change event of JS gets fired which is populating the drop down with the dataset from a ajax response.

How to stop on-change event to be fired if the user not clicked on the drop down and changed something.

Comment: You can check if the drop down has changed it's default value. Only then let the handler be triggered

Comment: @AndreiCacio Drop down default value is "--<SELECT-->". which is changed if the autofill option checked by user. And that is why onChange event fired by JS automatically.

Comment: Where is the code for the `<select>`? Also what triggers the change? Setting value will not automatically trigger change event

Comment: You have to do like if user click YES radio button then onchange cannot be fired ok? if user click manually on select or user click on NO radio button then select on change works am i right?

Comment: I have checked by putting an alert inside selectstate function that it is coming inside selectstate but I have not clicked on the state dropdown just values get set.

Comment: @PareshGami yes. So how to detect user manually clicked or not ? Because onChange triggered if the field value changed no matter user clicked or not. And that is the problem.

Comment: when user click YES then we have to prevent onChange event of select right?

Comment: yes kind of.  But if user manually click on the select drop down then we have to fire on change. So basically I want onchange to fire only if user clicks and change something in the drop down. Can you provide a working example ?

Comment: Answer posted please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100830/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-arjita-mitra).

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" value="1" name="rdChoice"> Yes! Set Default Value
<input type="radio" value="0" name="rdChoice"> No! I have to fill data

<hr>

First Name : <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName"><br>
Last Name : <input type="text" name="txtLastName" id="txtLastName"><br>

Country : 
<select onchange="getState()" id="selCountry">
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option>India</option>
    <option>Japan</option>
    <option>US</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function getState()
    {
        console.log("get state");   
    }

    $(function()
    {
        $( 'input[name="rdChoice"]:radio' ).change(
            function()
            {
                if(this.value==1)
                {
                    $("#txtFirstName").val("Paresh");
                    $("#txtLastName").val("Gami");
                    $("#selCountry").val("India");
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        );

    });

</script>
```

If user click on select box then and only getState is called.

Comment: I have resolved calling onchange function on setting value. But I can't set my drop down value. I am using the below code-  $('#idBillStateId').val($('#idBillStateId').attr('data-billStateId'));
            var cn = $('#idBillStateId').attr('data-billStateId');
            alert(cn);
            $('#idBillStateId option:selected').val(cn);